# error explicit type is missing('int assumed')

Tags: c++, class

I am getting this error, in my project and i can't seem to figure it out, the error is

> error explicit type is missing('int assumed)

This is what i have;

Ship.cpp

```
Ship::Ship(){
        rot = 0;
        position.x = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
        position.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;

        velocity.x = .2;
        velocity.y = .2;

        radius = 0;
}

float Ship::&rotateLeft(){
    if (rot < 0)
        rot += 360;
    rot-= velocity.x;
    return rot;
}

float Ship::&rotateRight(){
    if (rot > 360)
        rot -= 360;
    rot+= velocity.x;
    return rot;
}

float Ship::&getRot(){
    return rot;
}
```

Ship.h

```
#include "Physics.h"

class Ship : public Physics{
private:
    float rot;
public:
    float radius;
    XMFLOAT2 size;

    Ship();

    float &rotateRight();

    float &rotateLeft();

    float &getRot();
};
```

Physics.h

```
class Physics{
public:
    XMFLOAT2 position;
    XMFLOAT2 velocity;
};
```

This is weird because it is telling me that rot and velocity are undefined in my rotateleft function but it doesn't complain in the constructor. The same function is also giving me the error explicit type is missing('int assumed').

Comment: Should be `float &Ship::`.  Actually, in C++ it's usually written `float& Ship::`.

Comment: The compier usually reports the statement where it found an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand on your function return type should come *before* the class name; i.e. instead of this:

```
float Ship::&rotateLeft(){
```

... try this:

```
float & Ship::rotateLeft(){
```

Comment: Does altering the location of the deference operator changes anything like with int * const and int const *

Comment: No. That only works with pointers because you've got two options: either the pointer itself is const and therefore can't be pointed at something else (e.g. `int * const`), and/or the thing the pointer is pointing at is a const type (e.g. `const int *` or `int const *`). Doing both together would be `const int * const` or `int const * const`. Unlike pointers, you can never change what a reference points to, so only the second option applies (i.e. `const int &` or `int const &`).